# How to create 2 arrows rather than double headed arrow with Tikz

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, graphs

I want to display two separate arrows in this graph between nodes 1&4 and nodes 1&3. 
I read somewhere about bending the arrows, but I'd really like them to remain straight. Also saw there was an option to make them leave nodes at different angles but can't work out the code for this. Could someone help me please!

This is the code I have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
% vertices
\node[vertex] (1) at  (0,0) {$1$};
\node[vertex] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};
\node[vertex] (3) at  (0,-2) {$3$};
\node[vertex] (4) at  (2,-2) {$4$};
%edges
\draw[edge] (1) to (2);
\draw[edge] (1) to (3);
\draw[edge] (1) to (4);
\draw[edge] (2) to (3);
\draw[edge] (2) to (4);
\draw[edge] (3) to (1);
\draw[edge] (4) to (3);
\draw[edge] (4) to (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Graph]

I'd like it to look similar to this, with two arrows rather than one[image: graph 2]

Comment: Hi ! Could you show a picture of  what you want, please ?

Comment: I've added an image to demonstrate. (Please note the nodes are not it the same places)

Answer (score 7):

You can access the point on the edge of a node that is at a specific angle using `nodename.angle`. See an example below where I've used this.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
% vertices
\node[vertex] (1) at  (0,0) {$1$};
\node[vertex] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};
\node[vertex] (3) at  (0,-2) {$3$};
\node[vertex] (4) at  (2,-2) {$4$};
%edges
\draw[edge] (1) to (2);
\draw[edge] (1.260) to (3.100);
\draw[edge] (1.325) to (4.125);
\draw[edge] (2) to (3);
\draw[edge] (2) to (4);
\draw[edge] (3.80) to (1.280);
\draw[edge] (4) to (3);
\draw[edge] (4.145) to (1.305);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the anchor refer to the doc section 67 shape

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
  \tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex}}
  % vertices
  \node[vertex] (1) at  (0,0) {$1$};
  \node[vertex] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};
  \node[vertex] (3) at  (0,-2) {$3$};
  \node[vertex] (4) at  (2,-2) {$4$};
  % edges
  \draw[edge] (1.10) to (2.170);
  \draw[edge] (2.190) to (1.350);

  \draw[edge] (1) to (3);
  \draw[edge] (1.300) to (4.150);
  \draw[edge] (2) to (3);
  \draw[edge] (2) to (4);
  \draw[edge] (3) to (1);
  \draw[edge] (4) to (3);
  \draw[edge] (4.120) to (1.330);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]